# How to make sure timerseriesAI/tsai uses GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series

I am using tsai 0.3.5 for timeseries classification.
But it is taking unusual time for training an epoch.
Can somebody please let me know how to make sure that tsai uses GPU and not CPU.

Please find below my code.

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
from pickle import load
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np
from tsai.all import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

num_datesets = 1
for dataset_idx in range(num_datesets):
    X_train = load(open(r"X_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
    y_train = load(open(r"y_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
    X_test = load(open(r"X_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
    y_test = load(open(r"y_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
    print("dataset loaded")

    learn = TSClassifier(X_train, y_train, arch=InceptionTimePlus, arch_config=dict(fc_dropout=0.5))

    print("training started")
    learn.fit_one_cycle(5, 0.0005)
    learn.export("tsai_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl") 
    
    probas, target, preds = learn.get_X_preds(X_test, y_test)
    precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(target, probas)
    plt.clf()
    plt.fill_between(recall, precision)
    plt.ylabel("Precision")
    plt.xlabel("Recall")
    plt.title("tsai_"+str(dataset_idx)+"_precision_recall_curve")
    plt.savefig("tsai_"+str(dataset_idx)+".png")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
import os
os.environ["DEVICE"] = "cuda"
```

Increasing the batch size seems to resolve the issue. Default batch size in tsai was very small.